# When was the concept of V1 introduced?

Tags: aviation-history, takeoff, v-speeds

When was V1 speed first introduced? Was it the result of a particular accident or series of accidents?

Comment: One problem here would be that research of google ngrams of V1 will conflate the flying bomb

Comment: @CGCampbell You could search for "Takeoff Decision Speed" or related terms like "Accelerate Stop Distance" / "Accelerate Go Distance".

Comment: Google search for "balanced field length".  I'm guessing it started in the 60s.

Comment: @JohnK I did some searching: it was already part of [CAR 4b](https://lessonslearned.faa.gov/PanAm214/B707_regs_4b.pdf) § 4b.114 *Take-off speeds* in the version of December **1953**. Unfortunately, I could not find any older versions, so I don't know when it was actually introduced.

Comment: @Bianfable I'm surprised it goes back that far. I figured it would have started in jets.

Comment: @TomMcW, 1953 is a year after the De Havilland Comet was introduced, and had two accidents where it failed to lift off due to early and excessive rotation.

Answer (score 1):

There were a series of RWY overruns during the days of the first group of jet airliners (early to mid 50's), possibly 3 within a 12 month period. Mainly early rotation resulting in the airplane stalling during the takeoff roll at full thrust. Such accidents caused review of the take off maneuver and birth of the RTOW (Regulatory Take Off Weight) calculations.

A description of 2 cases, [26th Oct 1952 and 3rd Mar 1953](http://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?field=typecode&var=190%&cat=%1&sorteer=datekey&page=1)

Comment: Interesting info; other that taking the word of an *unknown somebody on the internet*, is there a link that those interested in this question can follow to get more information?

Comment: @Ralph J, I've added a link pointing at 2 related occurrences. Would appreciate if you did the same in case you follow up and find a more direct link between actual accidents and the intro of V1. An accident report or 'terms' of a committee given such task.